# Authentication is required to perform file operations?

Tags: permissions

I made a shared folder for multiple users on my computer. However one account (**Barry**) cannot access this folder without providing the root users password. Is there a way to disable this pre-caution?

It says:

> Authentication is required to perform file operations

**Barry** is fine with accessing other shared folders, and I have allowed **Barry** read/execute permissions of the folder; after typing the password.

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: My advice is: figure out what is different between user `Barry` and a user (let's call her `Alice`) who has the desired behaviour. This includes group memberships of `Barry` compared to those of `Alice` and ownership of the directories in question.  I'd guess `Barry` is not a member of a certain (required) group while `Alice` is.

Comment: Indeed, Each user on my computer have been allocated in different groups. All function as I want except Barry's. The group does have the correct permissions however it is the only one that has read/execute instead of rwx for the folder. the other groups can access this folder no problem. Just confused why Barry's needs root password before access.

Comment: Update your question with the output of `stat /directoryname` where `directoryname` is the directory Barry can't access. You will see one line that shows `Gid` (Group ID). Make sure Barry is a member of that group.